# Gatling scala extension fails with, could not find implicit value for evidence parameter

Tags: scala, gatling

Trying to run a gatling 3.0.2 with a neat exetension method that I have been using many times before with gatling 2.2.x

```
implicit class Extensions(val scenario: ScenarioBuilder) extends AnyVal {
def injectDefaults: PopulationBuilder =
  scenario.inject(
    rampUsersPerSec(RAMP_USER_PER_SEC) to LOAD_FACTOR during (RAMP_UP_TIME seconds),
    constantUsersPerSec(LOAD_FACTOR) during (DURATION seconds)
  )
```

}

But it no longer compiles, it fails with:

```
 could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type 
 io.gatling.core.controller.inject.InjectionProfileFactory[Product with Serializable with io.gatling.core.controller.inject.open.OpenInjectionStep]
  scenario.inject(
```

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution myself, was missing some implicit import. Here is the full code sample:

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef.{constantUsersPerSec, rampUsersPerSec,_}
import io.gatling.core.structure.{PopulationBuilder, ScenarioBuilder}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object Config {    
  val LOAD_FACTOR: Double = 50
  var RAMP_UP_TIME: Int = 10
  val RAMP_USER_PER_SEC = 0.1


  implicit class Extensions(val scenario: ScenarioBuilder) {
    def injectDefaults: PopulationBuilder =
      scenario.inject(
        rampUsersPerSec(RAMP_USER_PER_SEC) to LOAD_FACTOR during (RAMP_UP_TIME seconds),
        constantUsersPerSec(LOAD_FACTOR) during (DURATION seconds)
      )
  }

}
```