# Scala dynamic scenario

Tags: scala, gatling

Is there any way to create dynamic scenario perhaps like this? below code giving error not found: type scenario def my_test() : scenario = {. I think import is not required for scenario

```
    def my_test() : scenario = {
    if(condition) 
        scenario(build_name)
        .exec(http("post"+build_name+"content")    
        .post(end_point_url)
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token)
        .body(RawFileBody(input_file_path)).asXml
        .check(status is 200))
     else
        scenario(build_name)
        .exec(http("post"+build_name+"content")    
        .post(end_point_url)
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token)
        .body(RawFileBody(input_file_path)).asJson
        .check(status is 200))
}



setUp(my_test()
    .inject(
        nothingFor(2 seconds),
        constantUsersPerSec(users).during(10 seconds)
    ))
    .assertions(
        global.responseTime.mean.lt(threshold = mean_response_time),
        global.successfulRequests.percent.gte(minSuccessPercent)
     )
    .protocols(httpConf)
    .assertions(
        forAll.responseTime.max.lt(threshold = responseTime)
    )
```

EDIT
When I tried with

```
def my_test() = {
    if(condition) 
        scenario(build_name)
        .exec(http("post"+build_name+"content")    
        .post(end_point_url)
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token)
        .body(RawFileBody(input_file_path)).asXml
        .check(status is 200))
     else
        scenario(build_name)
        .exec(http("post"+build_name+"content")    
        .post(end_point_url)
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token)
        .body(RawFileBody(input_file_path)).asJson
        .check(status is 200))
}
```

it is giving following error

```
17:10:01.582 [main][ERROR][ZincCompiler.scala:151] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$
- ... .scala:132:2: method my_test has return statement; needs result type
        return scenario(build_name)
        ^ 17:10:01.645 [main][ERROR][ZincCompiler.scala:122] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - one error found 17:10:01.648 [main][ERROR][ZincCompiler.scala:219] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation crashed sbt.internal.inc.CompileFailed: null
        at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:242)
```

EDIT

Thanks for all who contributed to this post. I had to modify scenario to ScenarioBuilder with import statement io.gatling.core.structure.{PopulationBuilder, ScenarioBuilder} added as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239753/gatling-scala-extension-fails-with-could-not-find-implicit-value-for-evidence-p)

Comment: There is example where explain how to set scenario to variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61167486/gatling-is-it-possible-to-execute-concurrent-scenarios-in-a-simulation-dependin/61185570#61185570

Comment: Please provide the FULL code, not pieces of it. Otherwise, there's no way to tell what your code error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the compiler is saying, `scenario` is unknown (not actually a Gatling type by the way) and moreover it is not the type returned by your method.

You could either drop the return type and let the compiler infer it for you or write the proper return type.

EDIT: Zinc compiler used by Gatling needs an explicit return type, so you have to find out the right type (maybe `ScenarioBuilder`).

Comment: Gael, I am not good at scala. I tried to modify my code as  def my_test() : Unit = { ..... 
but getting below errors 16:46:01.094 enclosing method my_test has result type Unit: return value discarded
        return scenario(build_name)
        ^
.... .scala:146:3: value inject is not a member of Unit
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value inject'?
        .inject(
         ^
[main][ERROR][ZincCompiler.scala:122] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - one error found
[main][ERROR][ZincCompiler.scala:219] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Compilation crashed
sbt.internal.inc.CompileFailed: null

Comment: I recommend learning about Scala a bit then. `Unit` is a type. I suggested to just not write the return type: `def my_test() = { ... }`

Comment: Okay, Zinc compiler used in Gatling might need an explicit type. Then you need to find out the type of the expression, maybe your IDE can help you? I don't have one right now, maybe `ScenarioBuilder` is the type you are looking for but not sure..